# Trouble Looping Through an Array Where Index 0 is a Second Dimension Array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I've created an object in my code that represents a medical patient's chart. Each chart corresponds to one patient. Within each chart, a patient can have many visits, or "Encounters". Within each encounter, a patient can have several supporting documents.

I am having trouble looping through arrays where the first index [0] is another array.  In the code below, the compiler is complaining that (int j = 0; j < chart.DocumentIDs[i].Length; j++) is invalid because type object has no length property. However, the index at  DocumentIDs[i] is an Int32[].

I am trying to generate a string output that will list all contents of the patient's chart, broken down first by encounter and then by document ID.  Below is my code. If anyone can point out where I'm going wrong. I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{    
    string ChartOutput = "";
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //initialize new chart object
        var charts = new[]
        {
            new 
            { 
                  MRN= 745654, 
                  Encounters = new int?[]
                  {
                      10,11,12
                  }, 
                  DocumentIDs = new object []
                  { 
                      new int[]
                      {
                          110, 1101
                      }, null, 112 
                  }, 
                  DocumentTypes = new object[]
                  {
                      new string[]
                      {
                          "Consents", "H&P"
                      }, null, "Intake Questionnaire"
                  }, 
                  DocumentNames = new object[]
                  { 
                      new string[]
                      {
                          "Eartube Surgery", 
                          "Well-Visit Physical"
                      }, null, "Health Survey"
                  } 
              }                        
        };

        foreach (var chart in charts)
        {
            ChartOutput += " Patient MRN#: " +  
                           chart.MRN.ToString() +
                           " Has the following visits: 
                           " + Environment.NewLine + 
                           Environment.NewLine ; 

            for(int i =0; I < chart.Encounters.Length; i++)
            {
                ChartOutput += "Visit Number: " + 
                               chart.Encounters[i].ToString() + 
                               Environment.NewLine;

                if (chart.DocumentIDs[i] != null)
                {  
                    for (int j = 0; j < chart.DocumentIDs[j].Length; j++)
                    {
                        ChartOutput += "  Document ID:" + 
                                          chart.DocumentIDs[j].ToString() + 
                                          Environment.NewLine + 
                                          "  Document Type: " + 
                                          chart.DocumentTypes[j].ToString() +
                                          Environment.NewLine + "  Document Name: " +
                                          chart.DocumentNames[j].ToString() +
                                          Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                    }                                        
                }
                else 
                {
                    ChartOutput += "  Has No Documents" + 
                                   Environment.NewLine + 
                                   Environment.NewLine; 
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}




//ChartObject Class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CodeTester
{
    public class ChartObject
    {
        public ChartObject()
        {
            RecordClass = "Medical";
        }

        public string RecordClass {get; private set; }
        public int MRN { get; set; }
        public object [] Encounters { get; set; }
        public object [] DocumentIDs { get; set; }
        public object [] DocumentTypes { get; set; }
        public object [] DocumentNames { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1) spend some time formatting your code.  There shouldn't be any, or at least not much, horizontal scrolling.  2) Don't use `object[]` types like this.  Just...don't.  It looks like, in context, you should be creating new named types to represent a set of properties rather than an array since it's a fixed number of items of known static (and also different) types.  An array is just wrong for that; make a new class.

Comment: You explained why Encounters have documents.  Why does the chart have documents?  And why are those properties all object types?  Is there a constraint somewhere that requires all this boxing?  Don't put 'object' in class identifiers...it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The reason for the boxing is because the first element in each property may be another array, and sometimes it may not.

Comment: The chart has encounters, which in turn have documents.

Comment: _quicker to write it inline and is easy to read on my 24 inch monitor_ -- this is irrelevant to those of us consuming it _here_.

Comment: Have you looked at Jagged arrays (arrays of arrays)?  These arrays can contain other arrays, which appears to be the underlying problem you need to solve.

Comment: I also work in the medical field.  I find that the data types are often complex and nested.  Jagged arrays and recursion are powerful tools in the medical field for sure.  Classes which contain themselves come in handy in similar situations where jagged arrays can be used.  E.G. A `DocumentIDs` that has a `List<DocumentIDs>` as a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished what I set out to do by using jagged arrays instead of object arrays.  Below is the updated and formatted code, along with an image of the output it produces.

```
namespace CodeTester
{


    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {    
        string ChartOutput = "";
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //initialize new chart object
            var charts = new[]
         {
            new             
            { 
                  MRN= 745654, 

                  Encounters = new int?[]
                  {
                    10,11,12 
                  }, 

                  DocumentIDs = new int?[][]
                  { 
                      new int?[]{110, 1101}, null, new int?[] { 112 }
                  }, 

                  DocumentTypes = new string[][]
                  {
                      new string[]{ "Consents", "H&P"}, null,  new string[] 
                      { "Intake Questionnaire" }
                  }, 

                  DocumentNames = new string[][]
                  { 
                      new string[]{ "Eartube Surgery", "Well-Visit Physical"}, 
                      null, new string[] { "Health Survey" }
                  } 
              }                        
         };

                foreach (var chart in charts)
                {
                    ChartOutput += "Patient MRN#: " +  chart.MRN.ToString() +
                    " Has the following visits: " 
                   + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine ; 

                        for(int i =0; i< chart.Encounters.Length; i++)
                        {
                            ChartOutput += "Visit Number: " +
                           chart.Encounters[i].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

                            if (chart.DocumentIDs[i] != null)
                            {
                                for (int j = 0; j < chart.DocumentIDs[i].Length; j++)
                                    {
                                        ChartOutput += "    Document ID:" +  
                                        chart.DocumentIDs[i][j].ToString() + 
                                        Environment.NewLine + 
                                        "    Document Type: " + 
                                        chart.DocumentTypes[i][j].ToString() + 
                                        Environment.NewLine + 
                                        "    Document Name: " + 
                                        chart.DocumentNames[i][j].ToString() + 
                                        Environment.NewLine + 
                                        Environment.NewLine;                                     
                                    }                                        
                            }

                            else { ChartOutput += "    Has No Documents" +
                            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine; }
                        }

                }

        }

        private void Run_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {  
            MessageBox.Show(ChartOutput);            
        }
    }
}



// ChartObject Class

namespace CodeTester
{
    public class ChartObject
    {
        public ChartObject()
        {
            RecordClass = "Medical";
        }

        public string RecordClass { get; private set; }
        public int MRN { get; set; }
        public int[] Encounters { get; set; }
        public int?[][] DocumentIDs { get; set; }
        public string[][] DocumentTypes { get; set; }
        public string[][] DocumentNames { get; set; }

    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Since `DocumentIDs` is an array of `Object`, anything you retrieve by indexing into it will be of type `Object` as well - and will require a typecast before you can access any of its specific properties. And trying to access the `Length` property of each element by iterating is going to be dangerous: one element is an `Array`, one is `null`, and one is an `Integer`: only one of those *has* a `Length` method!

I agree with Servy's comment: you would be much better off declaring explicit types instead of stuffing properties into `Object` arrays. This approach is almost certainly going to be more trouble than it's worth.